# issue in composite kprimary key in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i have a problem, i need to add a composite primary key ( _id + col_Region ) to my table 
but i don't know how to proceed, i know to do it in the usual way, but i tried with this 
syntax it doesn't work :

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + MENAGE + 
  "(  " + _id +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"+ col_Region +" TEXT,"+ 
   LastModifiedTime +" TEXT,"+ Comune_Arrondis +" TEXT,"+ N_district +" INT ");
```

how to solve that, i looked for solution in the forum but i didn't found one , thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax would be:

```
CREATE TABLE menage (
_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
col_Region TEXT NOT NULL,
LastModifiedTime TEXT,
Comune_Arrondis TEXT,
N_district INT,
PRIMARY KEY (_id, col_Region)
)
```

or in terms of code:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + MENAGE +
"(  " + _id + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + col_Region + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
LastModifiedTime +" TEXT," + Comune_Arrondis + " TEXT, " + N_district +" INT, " +
"PRIMARY KEY ( " + _id + ", " + col_Region + "))";
```

So you declare all the columns first and then declare which columns form the primary key at the end. Note that the columns that form the primary key should be given the NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: thanks a lot, but i already know that, my issue is that i don't know how to do it with my syntax, that is my problem, thanks for responding

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by your syntax - I've updated the above with the statement in terms of a constructed string. If that's still not what you're after, could you explain the problem further?

Comment: thanks NigelK, that is exactly what i am after, i will try it and tell you results.